# Did Tolkien explain how biblical events relate to the Ainur in Arda?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

We know his story is a parallel universe of our real world, and we know he is a devout Christian. In his story universe, therefore, Illuvatar would have been the one true God, with the Valar and Maiar his agents on Earth to govern it till the end of days.

Did he ever suggest how, or why, biblical events occurred in his Middle Earth - for in that universe such events could only be of the actions and deeds of Illuvatar or the Ainur who have entered Middle Earth?

Comment: it is not a parallel universe, it is a fictional history of our world.

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack The two seem the same thing to me, but I'm not gonna pick on the specifics of definition. My question still stands, whichever term you use. I know that Middle Earth is our Earth in his story.

Comment: @thegreatjedi Fictional history = "This is what happened". Parallel universe - "This is what could have happened". That's the difference.

Comment: @MikeScott ok, so, how did he/did he ever explain what happened/could have happened when the biblical events occurred? In an Earth that emerged from the Fourth Age, how is Illuvatar and the Ainur associated with these events?

Comment: @thegreatjedi If you want an answer instead of a discussion about the wording of your question, I suggest you edit the question to say "fictional history" instead of "parallel universe".

Comment: @MikeScott With all due respect, my last comment was not a discussion of the wording. It was intended to be "ok, so, back to the question at hand, ...". I phrased it as "what happened/could have happened" just to satisfy either interpretation, even though I still don't see a difference. I can ask what happened when those events occurred, or I can ask what could have happened when those events occurred, and isn't it so that the answer is still the same? Aren't they equivalent in meaning? So, anyway, as I have been meaning to say, back to my question!

Answer (score 3):

I dont think there is anything written about Middle Earth after the Fourth Age so nothing from Tolkien on things such as Noah, Moses, Jesus etc, the last one I would assume would have to be some aspect of Eru made manifest.

The only possible parallel to a biblical story could be the reshaping of the world and the flooding of Belariand which *MIGHT* be seen as the origin of Noah's Flood in the Old Testament, merged in with the Alkallabeth where the chosen few escaped on boats. Though the Alkallabeth has always seem to sit more with Atlantis than anything in the bible.

Tolkien's feelings on allegory were well known:

> I cordially dislike allegory in all its manifestations, and always
>   have done so since I grew old and wary enough to detect its presence.
>   I much prefer history – true or feigned– with its varied applicability
>   to the thought and experience of readers. I think that many confuse
>   applicability with allegory, but the one resides in the freedom of the
>   reader, and the other in the purposed domination of the author.

So he may have purposefully shied away from anything that gave his books an air of "preaching", something his good friend C.S Lewis wasn't so bashful about.

Comment: Tolkien would not have allowed Jesus to be a Maia, he would have been an aspect of Eru. (Hence why the Tom Bombidill being Eru statement is silly)

Comment: Good point @AncalagonTheBlack how could I forget the trinity. I'll amend

Answer (score 1):

J.R.R. Tolkien was a believing Roman Catholic, but I don't know where he was on the spectrum of Bible belief between a total literal believer in every word and someone who considered most of the Old Testament to be figurative and/or fictional and/or exaggerated and inaccurate.

Ir seems obvious to me that there must have been at least one great catastrophe after LOTR and before the dawn of history to change the shape of lands and seas to those in modern times.  Tolkien wrote nothing about that as far as I know.

In one famous letter Tolkien wrote that the events in LOTR happened about six thousand years ago, or roughly about 4050 BC.  Another time Tolkien wrote that LOTR may have been about seven to eight thousand years ago or sometime between about 6050 BC to 5050 BC.

At what date does the Bible story begin with the creation of the world?  One scholar collected over two hundred different dates of creation.  Most creation dates cluster around 5500 BC and 4000 BC.  Other suggested dates range from 6984 BC to 3616 BC.

So the suggested date range of LOTR puts it within the range of dates suggested for the Biblical creation.  At best there might be a few centuries or up to 2,431 years between LOTR and the start of Genesis.  At worst LOTR might happen 2,844 years AFTER the creation and Noah's flood would be due soon after LOTR.

Also the archaeological record of ancient civilizations would begin centuries or a most a couple of millennia after LOTR, and written history would begin just centuries after that.

So if Tolkien ever thought of writing about how LOTR fits in with Bible stories and chronology and Catholic theology he probably thought it best NOT to tackle such a complex writing problem.

Comment: Tolkien does address these issues in his letters. The third age was roughly 6000 years ago, so 4000 BC and he admitted he wished he'd bared geology in mind when designing the world, but didn't bother trying to fix those inconsistencies or explain the changes.